# What is the difference between git subtree merge and git-subtree

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

I've just found git-subtree tool that some time ago became a part of main git repo
https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/

However I don't fully understand what functionality does this tool provide over the already existing "git read-tree" + "git merge -s subtree". Is the only purpouse of git-subtree - making the resultant commit history look better or does it have more functionality that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The commands you describe reads a subtree into a repository. The `git-subtree` command has many more options, as described by [the documentation.](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) Among others, you can (annotated for simplicity):

```
add::
    Create the <prefix> subtree by importing its contents
    from the given <refspec> or <repository> and remote <refspec>.
merge::
    Merge recent changes up to <commit> into the <prefix>
    subtree.
pull::
    Exactly like 'merge', but parallels 'git pull' in that
    it fetches the given commit from the specified remote
    repository.
push::
    Does a 'split' (see above) using the <prefix> supplied
    and then does a 'git push' to push the result to the 
    repository and refspec. This can be used to push your
    subtree to different branches of the remote repository.
split::
    Extract a new, synthetic project history from the
    history of the <prefix> subtree.  The new history
    includes only the commits (including merges) that
    affected <prefix>, and each of those commits now has the
    contents of <prefix> at the root of the project instead
    of in a subdirectory.  Thus, the newly created history
    is suitable for export as a separate git repository.
```

There are also a variety of flags that aid and manipulate the above. I believe all these options were available before via chains of plumbing commands. `git-subtree.sh` just wraps them and makes them considerably easier to execute.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the old subtree code before it got added to git as a contrib module: https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.sh you can see that the git subtree tool is really a more advanced wrapper around the lower level git subtree merging strategies.

It basically leverages those strategies in a sensible way to make subtree management much easier. Particularly the --squash stuff is really, really useful.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to have more options, `git subtree` also takes into account Git configuration.

But regarding `git subtree pull`, make sure to use Git 2.36+

When `git subtree` wants to create a merge, it used "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0ac270cf7c0d77b91670bda843578e943f5790bd/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> and let it be affected by end-users "`merge.ff`" configuration, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit 9158a35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9158a3564a970def3375a79e8f3f90927cd8e793) (01 Feb 2022) by [Thomas Koutcher (`koutcher`)](https://github.com/koutcher).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0ac270c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ac270cf7c0d77b91670bda843578e943f5790bd), 17 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9158a3564a970def3375a79e8f3f90927cd8e793): force merge commit
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Koutcher</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Johannes Altmanninger</sup>

> When `merge.ff` is set to `only` in `.gitconfig`, `git subtree pull` will fail with error
>
> ```
> fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
> ```
>
> But the command does want to make *merges* in these places.
>
> Add `--no-ff` argument to [`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9158a3564a970def3375a79e8f3f90927cd8e793/Documentation/git-merge.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> to enforce this behaviour.