# How to make an existing subdir as subtree for another git repo, with squashed commit?

Tags: git, git-subtree

First I wrongly copied another repo source straight to one bigger project, in a subdir. The original repo and subdir were changed both ever since that time. Now I have knowledge of git-subtree, I want to make the subdir as a real subtree so that I can easily sync the change from original repo.

I tried 'git-subtree split', then pull latest source from original repo, it just worked. However, I don't want the whole history, but '--squash' didn't work for 'split', here's my commands

```
git subtree split -P xxx-dir --onto==1940032
git remote add xxx https://github.com....
git fetch xxx
git subtree pull -P xxx-dir xxx master
# the pull worked, but whole history of xxx was imported too. '--squash' didn't work for above 'pull'

git subtree merge -P xxx-dir xxx/master --squash
# Can't squash-merge: 'xxx-dir' was never added.
```

Looked like squash only works for subtree added but not split.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was confused by [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt) and [git subtree merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)

they are different things but maybe git-subtree is a kind of wrapper of some [git subtree merge stuff](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.sh#L676)
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

This is a good answer about the differences between the two:
[What is the difference between git subtree merge and git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741249/what-is-the-difference-between-git-subtree-merge-and-git-subtree)

as far as I understood the easiest to do what you is to

## 1. delete the `xxx-dir` directory and commit the change

```
rm -r xxx-dir
commit -am "xxx subtree"
```

## 2. add the subtree

```
git subtree add --prefix=xxx-dir --squash xxx master
```

The downside is that doing this changes the main repo history with 3 commits:

1. the commit that deletes `xxx-dir`
2. the commit that "imports" the subtree with its history squashed as one commit
3. the commit that merges the imported subtree

As far as I understood this is a kind of limitation of git-subtree.

By the way, this should be [the source code of git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.sh) maybe someone more skilled than me can dig in it.

Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
git subtree pull -P xxx-dir xxx master
# the pull worked, but whole history of xxx was imported too. '--squash' didn't work for above 'pull'
```

It seems you didn't use --squash. Or are you trying to say you tried the command again, not as you've written it here, WITH --squash? `git subtree pull --squash -P xxx-dir xxx master`

... and Regarding:

```
git subtree merge -P xxx-dir xxx/master --squash
# Can't squash-merge: 'xxx-dir' was never added.
```

Which branch did you run this from? it seems like you're trying to merge in changes from the same branch you have checked out into a sub-folder of itself. Since the command fails, it can't merge. I don't think it's saying squash is the problem, it's just that it happens to be a squash style merge that is failing.