# What is the difference between "git subtree pull" and "git pull -s subtree"

Tags: git, git-subtree

We are having an issue where the command:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=Root squash root master
```

is pulling code from the root repository into the . directory of our repository instead of the Root directory.

This command has worked fine in the past.  The only difference is it has been a while since we have done a pull, so there are quite a few changes to merge.

I can't seem to find any official documentation on "git subtree", but there is a lot on the subtree merge strategy used with "git pull -s subtree".  What is the difference (if any)?

Comment: `git pull subtree` simply pulls from a remote called "subtree". It has nothing to do with subtrees...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between git subtree merge and git-subtree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741249/what-is-the-difference-between-git-subtree-merge-and-git-subtree)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git subtree` is an "alternative to submodules", see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt or 
https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec

`git pull -s subtree` or `git merge -s subtree` selects the subtree merge strategy: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

See also the answer to [When to use git subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407634/when-to-use-git-subtree)