# Share a folder across all Projects with git

Tags: git

I have a project `A` and another project `B`. These projects have the same `Models`.
So I want to share my `Models` folder from project `A` to projects `B` and can change the `Models` from both `A` and `B` projects.

I have tested submodule in git for handling this but submodule will clone the whole repository in my second project but I just want a single folder.

Comment: Use a dependency managers like npm?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is `git subtree`?

See for example this [blog article by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree) that sketches a comparison between `git subtree` and `git submodule`.

Also, that [SO question "When to use git subtree?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407634/when-to-use-git-subtree) may be worth reading.