# How to move a part of repo to another repo on each push

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a massive app and I want to move a part of my app to another repo on each push.
For example when I push

```
-assets
-themes
--theme-1
--theme-2
-pages
```

to repository `main` , `theme-1` be pushed to repo `main-theme-1` and so `theme-2` . also it would be better that the themes don't be push to `main` repo at all.
Is there anyway to do it?? ( automatically preferred :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get what you are asking for.  You *can* get some approximations.

Git repositories are made up of *commits*.  They don't hold files—at least not directly.  The *commits* hold files, but the commit itself is the unit of storage.  That's why `git log` shows you the commit hash IDs: each one is a usable thing, all by itself.

Each commit stores a *full snapshot of every file*.  You might think that this would take up a lot of space.  It would, except for cleverness: Git *compresses and de-duplicates* the files inside each commit.  They're not stored like regular files on your computer.  They're in a special form that only Git can read, and literally nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite.

This read-only property is a property of every internal Git object, in fact.  So not only are the files contained inside commits read-only, so are the commits themselves.  Git makes use of this in multiple ways.  In particular, the hash ID that identifies each commit is unique to *that one particular commit*, and consists of a cryptographic checksum of the commit's content.  This means that any two chunks of software that implement the Git transfer protocol can connect to each other, and one can then, in effect, say to the other: *I have commit _____ (fill in the blank with a hash ID), would you like it?*  The other Git can tell whether it has *that* commit just by checking the hash ID.  If it *does* have that commit, it has *every file*.

Not only that, but in all except *shallow* repositories, if the potential receiver has *that* commit, it also has *every earlier commit* and the sender is now done: there's nothing left to send.  If the receiver doesn't have that commit, the sender is obligated to offer the parent commit(s) of that commit.  This goes on until the sender has offered all the commits, or the sender and receiver have reached a point of shared commits.  So that's *how* the sender and receiver can negotiate a minimal set of files and commits to send, just by swapping a few hash IDs.

Anyway, the point of all this is that senders send—and receivers receive—*whole commits*.  The file de-duplication trick means that the sender knows whether the receiver has some file already, because the sender knows which *commits* the receiver has, and those commits (that the sender also has) have the file hash IDs in them.  So the sender only really has to send any *new* commits and *new* files, and the receiver automatically uses the duplicate files to fill out newly-received commits as needed.  It's all a very clever system, but it depends, fundamentally, on this hashing system and the idea that commits never change and that repositories only exchange whole commits.<sup>1</sup>

**What this means for you** is that `git push` sends some commits, and then that's it.  You can't send *part* of a commit somewhere else.  Every commit holds a full snapshot of every file.  The only way to send commits that have fewer files in them is ... to make commits that have fewer files in them.

There are some tools for doing this, such as `git-subtree`.  The subtree code is not currently maintained.  See [When to use git subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32407634/1256452)  The lack of maintenance would concern me if I were looking at using it.

The other tool for doing this, which *is* maintained, is Git's submodules.  These are described lightly in the same linked SO question, but basically a submodule is a way to say, in one Git repository: *Clone this other Git repository, into a sub-directory within the working tree I'll be using.*  Once your Git has cloned the other Git repository into that location, your Git uses the *detached HEAD* mode in the submodule to keep that submodule on one particular commit *in* that other Git repository.

This setup is kind of rigid and brittle and doesn't please many of its users.<sup>2</sup>  It does *work* though, and it can solve real problems.  Consider it as an option.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a recent deliberate weakening of this system with what Git calls *partial clones*, but they're still not really ready for everyday use.  Think of the weakening as a sort of game of Jenga, where we pull out bits of solid structure to make everything lighter.  If we pull out the wrong bit, the whole thing crashes down: oops!

<sup>2</sup>I've personally come to the conclusion that Submodules Are Wrong, and I have some thoughts about how to do them "right", but these thoughts have a long way to go before they might be realized in the form of any kind of usable code.

Comment: first of all, tanx ! and to the issue : so either I have to some how create a sub-directory OR use helps of dev-ops to some how transfer my files from main repo to other repo like pipe line, right?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.