Using Git subfolders on remote repo to push separate local repos
I have been allocated a single repository in a client's managed github space.  I have two local repositories that are independent that I need to push to this client repo.  I was considering just creating subtrees in the remote repository and just independently push each local repo to the appropriate subtree.  I'm not seeing this type of use case from my research and I'm not even sure if it's possible.  Of course the simple answer would be to get another client repo but they so far have not agreed to that.  As you can probably tell, I'm not a power git user so any help is appreciated.

Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository

@mkrieger1 Not really. It talks about submodules, but a submodule needs a repository of its own, and then we are back at square one.

I thought you were talking about having a repository in a subfolder of another repository. Are you looking for this then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407634/when-to-use-git-subtree

RJCurry, that's impossible. GitHub repositories and local repositories are of the same repository type, the correspond one-to-one. You cannot push two separate local repositories to one GitHub repository until you combine these local repositories into another local one.

What are these two local repositories? Is this code you created for your client? Are they truly independent? If, so why? Could you combine them into a single repository? For example, in my work as a web developer, I have in the past created separate repositories for frontend and backend. This always lead to issues when I deployed frontend changes that weren't supported by the backend. I now put all of the code in a single repo instead to avoid this kind of problem. Are you in a similar situation here?

Code-Apprentice  Not exactly.  One project is a library that is used in multiple ways and the other project is a web front end that uses the library, only one of the uses of the library.

IMHO, you could do that (using appropriate subfolders)... but then, everytime you clone or pull, you will be getting copies of both projects.
workaround:
In your case, a workaround I think works for you is to use a separate branch for each project. That way, everytime you pull a branch, you'd only be getting one instead of both.
best case:
But it would still be best to have separate repositories for each project. Try requesting another repo from your client. ;)
